# How to pass more than one constructor argument in a build_association call in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one, model-associations

The second argument in the build_foo call never makes it into `Foo#initialize` (i.e. `args[1]` is `nil`). Any suggestions so as to get two or more arguments passed into `Foo#initialize` while keeping `*args` the only argument to initialize?

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bar
    def initialize *args
        super()
        self.total = args[0] + args[1]
    end
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :foo
    def do_something
        build_foo 2, 3   # 3 never reaches Foo#initialize
        build_foo [2,3]  # args[0] == [2,3], which is not what's desired
        save!
    end
end
```

Comment: For your convenience: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question - you can't. Simply because build_foo has only one parameter defined in [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to), which is `arguments = {}`, so you should pass there only arguments hash to initialize your new record.

Also you don't need to call `#super` in `#initialize`, as AR::Base doesn't define `#initialize` itself.

Why do you *need* to pass 2 distinct arguments instead of arguments hash? Positional arguments doesn't tell you which value you set, and with AR objects you probably has more than one attribute in table.

Comment: Thank you MBO. In the real code (vs. the simplified version shown above), I was doing fine without an arguments hash because the arguments are all instances of different user-defined classes (i.e. args[n].is_a? ClassA, args[m].is_a? ClassB, etc). The argument position is not important since I was able to get the class via is_a? and therefore identify which argument it is. But now given your explanation I will consider taking a arguments {}. Thank you for your help.